# Correcting a bad click when voting

Tags: support, voting

I accidentally down voted something.  Left a comment, then realized I downvoted.
I tried to unclick it and I get a little popup box say "you voted 2 minuted ago your answer is locked in"

2 minutes ago?!?!  What the frig kind of policy is that?  I can understand 2 days ago. but immediately locking it in.

I think that needs review.

Comment: I agree. This is annoying to endless degrees.

Comment: Here's a third. A little more time would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can undo your vote if the underlying post is edited.

The default vote undo window -- assuming you left the vote in an up or down state -- is 5 minutes long.

Comment: Yeah well the edit thing doesn't help if the OP doesn't go back and edit.  Which is probably the case 90+% of the time.  5 minutes even ten minutes makes no sense to me.

Comment: @brew right, so you will have to edit it in that case; you have plenty of rep to do so.

Comment: Well that works, but isn't that a little weird, me editing just so I can undo a vote?  And I don't want to be swinging my rep around like that either.

Comment: I've done this before but it didn't feel right :(

Comment: Joe and Brew have it, IMHO. This doesn't seem right and what if you don't have the rep in the first place?